# How to install python3.6 in window ubuntu bash

Tags: python, linux, gcc, python-3.6, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use ubuntu 16.04 window bash on Window 10 build 15002 
I wanna use python3.6 in my window 10 bash. then i installed python3.6 tar ball.

I set it up following README file while installing,

```
$ ./configure; make; make test; sudo make install;
```

but, it has occurred an error while install.
The below is about "./confiugure"

```
➜  Python-3.6.0 ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for python3.6... python3.6
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... linux
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for --with-icc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/usr/local/develop/language/Python-3.6.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

this is config.log below

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by python configure 3.6, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

$ ./configure
## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = DESKTOP-44GISIR
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 4.4.0-43-Microsoft
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath_target_3702546
PATH: /mnt/c/Windows/System32
PATH: /mnt/c/Windows
PATH: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem
PATH: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
PATH: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs
PATH: /mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd
PATH: /mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin
PATH: /mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon
PATH: /mnt/c/Users/dydwl/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
PATH: /mnt/c/Program Files/Bandizip/7z
PATH: /mnt/c/Users/dydwl/AppData/Roaming/npm
PATH: /mnt/c/Users/dydwl/AppData/Local/atom/bin
PATH: /mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin
PATH: /mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2792: checking build system type
configure:2806: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2826: checking host system type
configure:2839: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2869: checking for python3.6
configure:2885: found /usr/bin/python3.6
configure:2896: result: python3.6
configure:3005: checking for --enable-universalsdk
configure:3052: result: no
configure:3075: checking for --with-universal-archs
configure:3090: result: no
configure:3240: checking MACHDEP
configure:3446: result: linux
configure:3467: checking for --without-gcc
configure:3490: result: no
configure:3493: checking for --with-icc
configure:3513: result: no
configure:3637: checking for gcc
configure:3653: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3664: result: gcc
configure:3893: checking for C compiler version
configure:3902: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3913: $? = 0
configure:3902: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,
objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/
usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudf
lap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --w
ith-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse
-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x
86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
configure:3913: $? = 0
configure:3902: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3913: $? = 4
configure:3902: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3913: $? = 4
configure:3933: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3955: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3959: $? = 1
configure:3997: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define _GNU_SOURCE 1
| #define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
| #define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
| #define _BSD_TYPES 1
| #define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
| #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
| #define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1
| #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4002: error: in `/usr/local/develop/language/Python-3.6.0':
configure:4004: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_MACHDEP_set=
ac_cv_env_MACHDEP_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_prog_PYTHON_FOR_GEN=python3.6
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##
ABIFLAGS=''
AR=''
ARCH_RUN_32BIT=''
ARFLAGS=''
BASECFLAGS=''
BASECPPFLAGS=''
BLDLIBRARY=''
BLDSHARED=''
BUILDEXEEXT=''
CC='gcc'
CCSHARED=''
CFLAGS=''
CFLAGSFORSHARED=''
CFLAGS_NODIST=''
CONFIGURE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=''
CONFIG_ARGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
DEFS=''
DEF_MAKE_ALL_RULE=''
DEF_MAKE_RULE=''
DFLAGS=''
DLINCLDIR=''
DLLLIBRARY=''
DTRACE=''
DTRACE_HEADERS=''
DTRACE_OBJS=''
DYNLOADFILE=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENSUREPIP=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='#'
EXT_SUFFIX=''
FRAMEWORKALTINSTALLFIRST=''
FRAMEWORKALTINSTALLLAST=''

(................... )

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
#define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
#define _BSD_TYPES 1
#define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
configure: exit 77
```

I think it is wired, i test to complie simple c source using gcc.

```
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf("This works\n");
   return 0;
}


$ gcc -o test test.c
```

That is result,

```
➜  Python-3.6.0 gcc -o test test.c
test.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
#include <stdio.h> 
                 ^          
compilation terminated.
```

Why my gcc can't read basic header about 'stdio.h'..?
and how resolve the installation issue in window 10 bash...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### NOTICE: This solution no longer works as the apt repository has been disabled by it's creator. [More details available here](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6).

Therefore as Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will not be supported after April 30th 2021.
The best solution is where possible to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Old answer for posterity ...

The other answer is completely correct, however if you need pip as well (I would find it hard to use Python without pip), you would also need to install pip from inside a Virtual Environment (venv).  First install Python 3.6 as previously stated ...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.6
```

In each Python 3.6 project create a venv (from inside the projects directory) and install pip like so ...

```
python3.6 -m venv env --without-pip
source env/bin/activate
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

Comment: when i try to 'add-apt-repository' windows ubuntu bash tells me 'unable to locate package add-apt-repository'. Is there a way to install that?

Comment: Try running "sudo apt install software-properties-common && sudo apt update".

Comment: I get 

`403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I have updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 20):

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install python3.6`

Comment: Works great, thanks. Please, fix typo from 'Lsudo' to 'sudo'.